# How to "undraw" a box in an image using PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, python-imaging-library

Essentially, I have a function that draws a small box around where the user clicks on an image by using the ImageDraw.Draw.rectangle method in PIL. It works great, but the problem is, I need the ability so that when the user clicks inside the new box, it should get deleted. However, since the box becomes part of the image, I can't do this.

Are there any ways around this? Is there a library outside of PIL that would make this easier?

Thanks!

Comment: Have secondary layer, where you add the box and hide/unhide that layer accordingly.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate? How do I create a secondary layer for an image file in PIL? And even if I did that, how would I erase the box in the secondary layer? Are you recommending another layer for every box the user creates?

Comment: You should have two images, where box is drawn in a image with transparent background. Draw UI 1st and the "box layer image" on top of it (redraw only pixels, which are not "transparent" e.g. black).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to keep a pristine, un-annotated copy of your basic, background image and to keep a list of annotations ( that's what I am calling the squares you mention), like this:

- square, black, 10, 10, 20, 20
- square, red, 100,110, 200,210
- circle, green, 50,50, 25
- rectangle, blue, 30,30, 40,300

Then each time you re-paint the screen, take a copy of your background image and loop through the list of annotations drawing each one on.

When it comes time to delete, go through the list and delete the entry with the nearest centre, and re-paint your screen.

You could combine this approach with @Mika72's suggestion in the comments. So you would have your original, clean image and a separate image for your overlays which is the same size and starts out as an empty purely transparent canvas. Draw your annotations (squares and rectangles) onto this layer as the user clicks and each time you re-paint your screen, composite the annotation layer over the original image. Now you only have to iterate through the list of annotations and re-draw them when one is deleted, so re-paints will be faster.

---

Another option is *"rubber banding"* by drawing with an XOR, see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28760674/2836621).