# How to erase drawings made on a PIL Image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to dynamically draw shapes onto a PIL Image object and change those shapes based on user inputs. To do this, it would be helpful to erase previous drawings on the PIL images. I'm working in Jupyter notebooks to use the `display()` function.

I've already found a sort of workaround involving keeping two copies of the images in memory (`im` and `im_draw`), and modifying the `im_draw` by adding the drawing, then displaying `im_draw`, and then assigning `im_draw = im.copy()` but it's definitely not an elegant solution.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from skimage import data
from IPython.display import display

im = Image.fromarray(data.astronaut()) # This is an example image but you could use Image.open('eg_image.jpg')
display(im)
# Draw the rectangle on im_draw
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.rectangle((120, 120, 380, 380), width=10, outline='red')
display(im)

# I would like to erase the drawing here, if possible, e.g.
# im.erase_drawing(), such that display(im) showed the original image

#########################

# Temporary workaround; Alternative Approach
im = Image.fromarray(data.astronaut())
im_draw = im.copy()
# Draw the rectangle on im_draw
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im_draw)
draw.rectangle((120, 120, 380, 380), width=10, outline='green')
display(im_draw)
im_draw = im.copy() # Resets im_draw to im
display(im_draw)
```

The alternative approach works, but is more memory-intensive and ideally I would just be able to erase the drawing from `im`. Please let me know if you have any ideas for how to do this.

Comment: If you're using jupyter notebooks, I don't think you should worry about the additional memory needed to make a copy of a picture.

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey Good point, but it's still a relevant topic. Consider if I wanted to apply `n` drawings to an image but only remove the top `m` drawings from the stack. I don't want to create and maintain a copy of each state of the image, so it would be a good capability to be able to erase indexed or labelled drawings from a PIL Image.

Comment: If your code is representative and your *"drawings"* are rectangles and simple shapes, you could, much more economically in terms of memory, *"remember"* just your base image and then a list of the shapes (i.e. like SVG vector graphics, storing just top-left and bottom-right corner and colour) that you have drawn on, then you can re-create your image as it was at any point.

Comment: Similar idea here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54646154/2836621